# pip can't install new packages

Tags: python, docker, pip

We have a strange bug in our project, on our server a newly added package can't be installed with the following error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement minify-html==0.6.8 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for minify-html==0.6.8
```

This is in a docker container and doesn't make any sense, as all other packages were installed previously and even after pruning the docker system and trying to install without pip cache. The same thing happened with a colleague with another one of our other recently added packages.

It seems that pip can't install new packages. After deleting the virtualenv on colleagues computer the same thing still happens.

This is the docker file:

```
FROM python:3.10.0rc2-alpine3.14
WORKDIR /src
COPY requirements.txt /src/
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apk update \
    && apk add build-base gcc python3-dev musl-dev mariadb-connector-c-dev libffi-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY src/ /src/
```

The complete output log is:

```
Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp38-none-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/93/fbde0f7c68f324622932dc5f471f96941b76b70507b05c97ade605786cbb/minify_html-0.6.5-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=420c26667b5d1a830badaf43f23812b1119929a5c695628610d1084637161981 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/d8/e6356a7ee9f43dc821cac3a9411d02a1fc1be3089cdf93a8b5459c88e632/minify_html-0.6.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=fe23bd8762fbf5837886af2936d63bc10c4588276945f161d755c75878cd752c (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/56/28edcfeb4c16ede54358870244fa2cf067528a43733b509e31f80841332b/minify_html-0.6.5-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=5dfe7530d7a164e12ff69fd250970466a519feb3b73e19860dfe9eda031f01fb (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-none-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/38/ea6e2d63ed11c1c8df16073abfdf7642f25041aa3eca60bfb3633921dd20/minify_html-0.6.5-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=a5bd94f91fde1776e8a7f341ad15639ebd2d27a1604c6901491b19f186037993 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/d9/92fb1842f5d6ad1667ee6f15f20dfda770adee4f7a2f8eac165fa2ca0c21/minify_html-0.6.6-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=0fc30834af647c67afbee5230cac046aafcf052333518d88645bcdd0791fb87a (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/46/b12784385efc996682b34f97a3c18666f8f30d256f8b7f975c2b5715eee5/minify_html-0.6.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=3705fd23cb8863ddd9b38e7030a07cfe211b4818efa0a3d82b4047d7afc321a7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/b0/9d071ae4e8aee76d6eff7f11228b93cf1c99d8fccc420e392518da6a8475/minify_html-0.6.7-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=3c42784dad3efd892b78fdb8d2b600161cf69937abeb31c7122dac460970dfec (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/db/8bde23363a9073df07b113798341c5a5f419560843a16be1e79760704dce/minify_html-0.6.7-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=feeb8bd97623c82975003706c95679a1a558ac7b306a68fbde23278ce8171f3c (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp37-none-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/da/4eef42c5c23c5def297c4b56e91f0c5f2ee7939fa045cea8116e96035102/minify_html-0.6.7-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=dedb68a9de8d099bbbcc35aa2321457bb8ae36bed5e09fa42b1f932676fb434a (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/6e/2c048fd2348f1e38d35baf3857411adbd0a26f27b0a1b97cb0e35c109e81/minify_html-0.6.7-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=4ea81762ad9af1e6fae2bbc7d7286c3d85445c2afb76485d4adcae678232633e (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/90/e96dc296eb84a3281ae5a84998a7429ea833cdb1878be32ce762925658c6/minify_html-0.6.7-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=52a603da3735e75aad835a06e7372bc676ced3727053654cf7f62f1fd6117ac1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp38-none-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/08/fad195b197de8af9ec51ea73f5f8eda80a94fd76f625673e0e29a60cb5ca/minify_html-0.6.7-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=f0b715ee807685526f71348b7b247f3b2c7c32de899b5b3dc6d7db9e7d19c6ca (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/43/2fb8fc0cddbc63cb1890dd7340a3747b4800bf5ddc14e52db136c3763dc5/minify_html-0.6.7-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=f7f965e2213c08a8c32070cda813b9f09bff2b617195a4fb3c84012b8297c49d (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/f8/e64ae6b24aaa7981471b78721b093a503c634ec166c09582368aff132d7e/minify_html-0.6.7-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=9f2a886400084e2fe176a77df7729f53f676b849c01e3b0202387e6de8ad2079 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-none-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/bc/34cc8876d499615a5b2abcf432c7a871372724e5052a6abc1cddbd3f8e4f/minify_html-0.6.7-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=64e67da68a72690962ede804683317b098683f77bcfa1821990a47c87b405594 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/19/30e86456fd868bcb4d5d668cc1858257421b0b947e4bf590cf36cbb3cf01/minify_html-0.6.8-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=102951dd7bf9edb3d5a4b1cf61a2f8d1288bb78d65d271d755066eef15470deb (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/be/30cf2f514bb99adecff12192a0fad1a83346080ad2a3d31fff70afffb9f7/minify_html-0.6.8-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=d5c5e2dea59fe8126255e19440986fa4efda0c90257d4ca969cf2dcf3d71f6dd (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp37-none-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/0f/63fe4933ffbcdf541378bde81088b7b6249c7d7ce1ef7262d9a3de248095/minify_html-0.6.8-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=0b65ce125e067a1f09330a57d8f8258e4b129b0a3e59da280c17418e6ca93851 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/ef/d3273e182f6702ff18d9096e731ddfa50f08b4216fa6916d01cb3f993bf9/minify_html-0.6.8-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=7592755e8443797eb4f9318cc6210bd7d41ed9b1b3bbb8cd4f6b6d3cd70d8b49 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/c2/69bbf7954acdddc721662f0633244ed4a338c35e69d19c1e04d797216653/minify_html-0.6.8-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=6f71d394e0716308d2ee071dbefa0610c5b41470d84530c19ed6e24b5fb4ad37 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp38-none-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/c0/9eb12d5d1b784e5c9abc211e09cf3450c44bb51b81250a0ba5534c2c87e8/minify_html-0.6.8-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=bf80e98af59da582b9284da973d8500795597db2c8c77b8ca4ce5cebc3ce2d5c (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/ea/d780084e64e0d4077ceaf1a463a8c2f21987861bde5e02a4806d59013e37/minify_html-0.6.8-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=17e7c0049671662e65bdfc962bb30b0274243f06d9f763c60e18ce5664a7f5df (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/d1/0c35e014c195abb93721486abf99fc0d990c9de5781f7cdfba0b41d6e1ae/minify_html-0.6.8-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=4ae273af47975dfb3ecd15ff210663cce0fef053286aa083bfb820b7b8db8faa (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp39-none-win_amd64) are compatible (run pip debug --verbose to show compatible tags): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/b8/a6cf5dee3994de4b38b3970b25988dc87542524aeffa54f7b1a62e391e62/minify_html-0.6.8-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=6057732b03fa4ee995b72cf3a3cabfbd8d590a8bdc09a97c431ffa861e23a703 (from https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/)
Skipping link: not a file: https://pypi.org/simple/minify-html/
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'minify-html': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement minify-html==0.6.8 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for minify-html==0.6.8
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    raise RequirementsConflicted(criterion)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.RequirementsConflicted: Requirements conflict: SpecifierRequirement('minify-html==0.6.8')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 343, in resolve
    raise ResolutionImpossible(e.criterion.information)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionImpossible: [RequirementInformation(requirement=SpecifierRequirement('minify-html==0.6.8'), parent=None)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 103, in resolve
    raise error from e
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for minify-html==0.6.8
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-dgj5z89h'
Service 'web_dev' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -vvv -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'build-dev' failed
make: *** [build-dev] Error 1
```

Comment: Try to run pip in verbose mode and add the output to your question - `pip install -vvv ...`

Comment: Try a stable Python release. 3.10 is not released yet

Comment: Maybe you need to use pip3? On some distos 'python' and 'pip' are reserved for the python2 versions and 'python3' and 'pip3' for python3?

Comment: alternatively, don't use alpine. It has weird behavior with some `pip` packages.

Comment: @DeepSpace We ran into the issue in python:3.8.3-alpine and upgraded because we thought it might help.

Comment: @roman_ka No the python container only has pip3 installed.

Comment: Build on roman_ka's comment: you can also use `python3 -m pip`. This ensures that `pip` is installing into the correct python version (for example, 3.8.10).

Comment: If you're curious, check out my preferred image for python [here](https://gist.github.com/rnag/4e845ea85c79493978944998bdb1aa4f). It uses ubuntu base image which is similarly optimized for container size.

Comment: Why not to use alpine for Python images: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

Comment: @kmaork Thanks for the tip! Added it to the question.

Comment: I switched our project to debian now really quick and everything works again. Still am interested in a solution, as building takes a lot longer now.

Comment: Currently the problem is that `minify-html` did not release a source distribution for version 0.6.8, and also did not release python3.10 wheels for that version. You can go back to a stable python version and show us the logs, but the problem is probably the missing source distribution and the fact that you are using alpine, which reduces the chance to find a matching wheel.

Comment: There is no [3.10](https://pypi.org/project/minify-html/0.6.8/#files) wheel. I also see similar error when I forget that I'm on an unsupported version - for ex. 3.5 which most libs don't support nowdays.

Comment: @creyD Long shot but did you figure out the root cause for this? Facing the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76918323/pip-cannot-install-some-python-packages-due-to-missing-platform-tag-in-m1-mac

Comment: @Vinay Thanks for reminding me of this. No I didn't figure this out, we switched the container image.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that the version of the package is still maintained or available.Or try installing the packages individually without installing using requirements.
It worked for me.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/minify-html/ This project ist still maintained

Comment: it's the latest version, so this is wrong facts